# How to resize text inside Scene2D TextButton upon window resize?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

In my resize function, I create a new TextButtonStyle, assign it the new font I create with a FreeTypeFontGenerator and assign the button the new style. The end result still looks like the old font stretched to fit the new dimensions whereas I'd prefer to have a cleanly generated font.

This is the extent of my guess at a solution, which hasn't worked. I've looked in the docs and online, but I may have missed something. Thanks for reading.

```
    style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.font = Utils.createFont(50);
    startButton.setStyle(style);
    startButton.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If we instead create the stage as `new Stage(new ScreenViewport())`, we get some fairly acceptable behavior. The elements are not stretched but rather retain their original size, with the new space simply left blank. This seems a reasonable outcome. There are viewports other than ScreenViewport you can try creating for possibly other results.